# Laravel route pass variable to controller not same

Tags: php, laravel

I found a different error. I tried to delete book by id.
i have data for example

```
--------------
| id |  name |
--------------
| 1  | book1 |
| 2  | book2 |
| 3  | book3 |
```

so, when I will delete books with id 2, then the controller always receives id 3.
and when i tries to delete id 1, that remains the case, the controller gain id 3 (always the last record)

this view blade

```
@foreach($datas as $data)
<a href="# {{ $data->id }}"
   onclick="event.preventDefault();
   document.getElementById('remove-form').submit();"
  rel="tooltip" title="Hapus" class="btn btn-danger">
</a>

<form id="remove-form" action="{{ url('/dashboard/book/delete/'. $data->id) }}" method="post">
    {{ csrf_field() }}
    {{ method_field('DELETE') }}
</form>
@endforeach
```

this route

```
Route::group(['namespace' => 'Backend'], function ()
{
   Route::resource('/dashboard/book', 'BookController'); //
   Route::delete('/dashboard/book/delete/{id}', 'BookController@destroy');
}
```

this controller

```
public function index()
    {
        $datas = Book::all();
        return view('backend.bookview', compact('datas'));
    }
public function destroy($id)
{
    Book::where('id', $id)->delete();
    return redirect('/dashboard/book')->with('ok', translate('back/book.destroyed'));
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening because `document.getElementById('remove-form').submit()` always selects the last form which has `id` => `3`.

So change it to following code and it will work:

```
@foreach($datas as $data)
    <form method="POST" action="{{ url('/dashboard/book/delete/'. $data->id) }}"  style="display: inline-block;">
        {{ csrf_field() }}
        {{ method_field('DELETE') }}
        <button onclick="return confirm('Do you really want to delete this item?');" type="submit" class="btn btn-danger" data-original-title="Delete Item" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="">
            Delete
        </button>
    </form>
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE**

You can't have multiple id `remove-form` on a single html page. Instead use classes like this:

```
@foreach($datas as $data)
    <div class="delete-block">
        <a href="# {{ $data->id }}"
          rel="tooltip" title="Hapus" class="btn btn-danger delete-btn">
        </a>

        <form class="remove-form" action="{{ url('/dashboard/book/delete/'. $data->id) }}" method="post">
            {{ csrf_field() }}
            {{ method_field('DELETE') }}
        </form>
    </div>
@endforeach
```

and your script should go as:

```
$(function() {

    $('.delete-btn').on('click', function(e) {
        $(this).closest('.delete-block').find('form').submit();
    });

});
```

```js
$(function() {

  $('.delete-btn').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
   console.log($(this).closest('.delete-block').find('form').attr('action'));
    // $(this).closest('.delete-block').find('form').submit();
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="delete-block">
  <a href="#1" rel="tooltip" title="Hapus" class="btn btn-danger delete-btn">
    Delete 1
  </a>

  <form id="remove-form" action="/dashboard/book/delete/1" method="post">
      <input type="hidden">
  </form>
</div>

<div class="delete-block">
  <a href="#2" rel="tooltip" title="Hapus" class="btn btn-danger delete-btn">
    Delete 2
  </a>

  <form id="remove-form" action="/dashboard/book/delete/2" method="post">
      <input type="hidden">
  </form>
</div>

<div class="delete-block">
  <a href="#3" rel="tooltip" title="Hapus" class="btn btn-danger delete-btn">
    Delete 3
  </a>

  <form id="remove-form" action="/dashboard/book/delete/3" method="post">
      <input type="hidden">
  </form>
</div>
```

**Inside Controller**

You should delete the book by fetching the single record by id from database, like this:

```
public function destroy($id)
{
  $book = Book::find($id);
  if($book) {
    $book->delete();
    return redirect('/dashboard/book')->with('ok', translate('back/book.destroyed'));
  }
  // return error response - book deletion failed!
  return redirect('/dashboard/book')->with('Error', translate('back/book.destroyed.error'));
}
```

Use [`find()`](https://laravel.com/api/5.3/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Builder.html#method_find) to fetch single record via `primary key`, from database.

However, if you know the primary key of the model, you may delete the model without retrieving it. To do so, call the destroy method:

```
Book::destroy(1); // Can pass single primary key
Book::destroy([1, 2, 3]); // Can pass an array of primary keys
Book::destroy(1, 2, 3); // Can pass multiple primary keys via arguments
```

> See more about [Deleting Models in Laravel](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent#deleting-models)

Hope this helps!

Comment: but id parameter that I pass on the route when it came to controller the  params id turns into the id of the last record

Comment: dashboard/book/delete/2  going to destroy

in controller receives destroy(3) isnt 2, I feel confused sir

Comment: Wait, I am updating my answer!

Comment: yes, I have a check, sir
thanks for your attention :-D